# Redefining the Index in a Pandas DataFrame object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to re-index a pandas `DataFrame` object, like so,

```
From:
            a   b   c
        0   1   2   3
        1  10  11  12
        2  20  21  22

To :
           b   c
       1   2   3
      10  11  12
      20  21  22
```

I am going about this as shown below and am getting the wrong answer. Any clues on how to do this?

```
>>> col = ['a','b','c']
>>> data = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]],columns=col)
>>> data
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  11  12
2  20  21  22
>>> idx2 = data.a.values
>>> idx2
array([ 1, 10, 20], dtype=int64)
>>> data2 = DataFrame(data,index=idx2,columns=col[1:])
>>> data2
     b   c
1   11  12
10 NaN NaN
20 NaN NaN
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: because you are using the 1st DF to build the second, this will only get the rows where idx2 intersect the data.index, ie. row 1

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Why don't you simply use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#add-an-index-using-dataframe-columns) method?

```
In : col = ['a','b','c']

In : data = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]],columns=col)

In : data
Out:
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  11  12
2  20  21  22

In : data2 = data.set_index('a')

In : data2
Out:
     b   c
a
1    2   3
10  11  12
20  21  22
```

Comment: In order to remove the index name, as in the original example: data2.index.name = None

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want 'a' in the index

In :

```
col = ['a','b','c']

data = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]],columns=col)

data
```

Out:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  11  12
2  20  21  22
```

In :

```
data2 = data.set_index('a')
```

Out:

```
     b   c
a
1    2   3
10  11  12
20  21  22
```

In :

```
data2.index.name = None
```

Out:

```
     b   c
 1   2   3
10  11  12
20  21  22
```

Comment: The second Out is not correct. There is still an unnamed column on the left containing 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid index name with a single-liner, you can use `set_index('a')` with `rename_axis(None)`

```py
In [8]: data.set_index('a').rename_axis(None)
Out[8]: 
     b   c
1    2   3
10  11  12
20  21  22
```

---

Details

```
In [9]: data
Out[9]: 
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  11  12
2  20  21  22
```