# Could pandas use column as index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
Locality    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009

ABBOTSFORD  427000  448000  602500  600000  638500
ABERFELDIE  534000  600000  735000  710000  775000
AIREYS INLET459000  440000  430000  517500  512500
```

I don't want to manually swap the column with the row. Could it be possible        to use pandas reading data to a list as this:

```
data['ABBOTSFORD']=[427000,448000,602500,600000,638500]
data['ABERFELDIE']=[534000,600000,735000,710000,775000]
data['AIREYS INLET']=[459000,440000,430000,517500,512500]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redefining the Index in a Pandas DataFrame object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457584/redefining-the-index-in-a-pandas-dataframe-object)

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Yes, with [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) you can make `'Locality'` your row index.

```
data.set_index('Locality', inplace=True)
```

If `inplace=True` is not provided, `set_index` returns the modified dataframe as a result.

Example:

```
> import pandas as pd
> df = pd.DataFrame([['ABBOTSFORD', 427000, 448000],
                     ['ABERFELDIE', 534000, 600000]],
                    columns=['Locality', 2005, 2006])

> df
     Locality    2005    2006
0  ABBOTSFORD  427000  448000
1  ABERFELDIE  534000  600000

> df.set_index('Locality', inplace=True)
> df
              2005    2006
Locality                  
ABBOTSFORD  427000  448000
ABERFELDIE  534000  600000

> df.loc['ABBOTSFORD']
2005    427000
2006    448000
Name: ABBOTSFORD, dtype: int64

> df.loc['ABBOTSFORD'][2005]
427000

> df.loc['ABBOTSFORD'].values
array([427000, 448000])

> df.loc['ABBOTSFORD'].tolist()
[427000, 448000]
```

Answer (score 17):

You can change the index as explained already using `set_index`.
You don't need to manually swap rows with columns, there is a transpose (`data.T`) method in pandas that does it for you:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame([['ABBOTSFORD', 427000, 448000],
                    ['ABERFELDIE', 534000, 600000]],
                    columns=['Locality', 2005, 2006])

> newdf = df.set_index('Locality').T
> newdf

Locality    ABBOTSFORD  ABERFELDIE
2005        427000      534000
2006        448000      600000
```

then you can fetch the dataframe column values and transform them to a list:

```
> newdf['ABBOTSFORD'].values.tolist()

[427000, 448000]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another simple approach is to assign the column to the data frame index

```py
data = {
  'Locality': ['ABBOTSFORD', 'ABERFELDIE', 'AIREYS INLET'],
  '2005': [427000, 534000, 459000 ],
  '2006': [448000, 448000, 448000],
  '2007': [602500, 602500, 602500],
  '2008': [600000, 710000, 517500],
  '2009': [638500, 775000, 512500]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# set the locality column as the index
df.index = df['Locality']
```

And if you no longer want the Locality column as a column, you can just drop it

```py
df.drop('Locality', axis=1)
```

You'll end up with

```sh
              | 2005     | 2006   | 2007   | 2008   | 2009
Locality      |-------------------------------------------              
ABBOTSFORD    | 427000   | 448000 | 602500 | 600000 | 638500
ABERFELDIE    | 534000   | 448000 | 602500 | 710000 | 775000
AIREYS INLET  | 459000   | 448000 | 602500 | 517500 | 512500
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the column index using **index_col** parameter available while reading from spreadsheet in Pandas.

Here is my solution:

1. Firstly, import pandas as pd: 
   `import pandas as pd`
2. Read in filename using **pd.read_excel()** (if you have your data in a spreadsheet) and set the index to 'Locality' by specifying the index_col parameter.

   `df = pd.read_excel('testexcel.xlsx',  index_col=0)`

   At this stage if you get a 'no module named xlrd' error, install it using `pip install xlrd`.
3. For visual inspection, read the dataframe using `df.head()` which will print the following output
   [image: sc]
4. Now you can fetch the values of the desired columns of the dataframe and print it

   [image: sc2]