# How to create a set_index with 2 names in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I try use:

```
df_bm = pd.df_bm('player': [1, 2])
```

but appears

```
File "<ipython-input-36-adaefa2ccfb5>", line 1
df_bm = pd.df_bm('player': [1, 2])
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html. You should use `df_bm.set_index(keys)` (where keys could be ['colname1', 'colname2']) . set_index will take both a single column name and a list of multiple column names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could pandas use column as index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542419/could-pandas-use-column-as-index)