# Display all IDs in a group only once (excel format) using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dateframe:

```
idx_value   val1    val2
idx            1    5
idx            2    6
idx            3    7
idx            4    8
```

I wonder if it is possible to convert table in html as following:

```
    val1    val2
       1    5
idx    2    6
       3    7
       4    8
```

I only want to show idx once. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redefining the Index in a Pandas DataFrame object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457584/redefining-the-index-in-a-pandas-dataframe-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like a `groupby` + `replace` + `set_value`:

```
df['idx_value'] = df.groupby('idx_value')['idx_value']\
         .apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.*', '').set_value(len(x) // 2 - 1, x[0]))

df

  idx_value  val1  val2
0               1     5
1       idx     2     6
2               3     7
3               4     8
```

Comment: I thought multi-indexes, but this one seems reasonable. thank you

Comment: @galaxyan Multi-Index would place the value at the top, and besides, you need two columns for a multi-index :)